# DatePicker's selection is different from the returned date

Tags: swiftui

The selection is 9/16/21, but the returned date is 9/16/20. The returned date is not synchronised somehow. There is nothing special here, it's just standard usage of DatePicker. Is it a bug of DatePicker? How to workaround this issue?

```
DatePicker(selection: $model.returnDate, in: model.returnDateRange, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("Return Date")
}
```

[Full Source Code](https://gist.github.com/unchartedworks/23ce24a6add499fba968ecd080b640eb)

How to reproduce:

Change the first date picker's year to 2020. If you want to do it again, just change the first DatePicker's date to 2021, 2022...
[image: DatePicker]

Comment: It seems to be a combine issue. The picker is returning the right data. You can verify that by printing the value in the `didSet { ... }` of the returnDate property. In fact, if you set the message text in the didSet closure, it works fine. It seems the sink closure executes a little too soon. I ran out of time for the moment, but will resume later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug of DatePicker.

It can be worked around by using departure publisher to update return date.

```
DatePicker(selection: $model.returnDate, in: model.returnDateRange, displayedComponents: .date) {
        Text("Return Date")
    }
    .onReceive(model.$departureDate, perform:model.updateReturnDate)


func updateReturnDate(_ date: Date) {
    if date > returnDate {
        returnDate = date
    }
}
```